# Fixed top and bottom divs, Mobile keyboard issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, iphone, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using straight forward bootstrap to implement like a mobile chat website.
Experiencing css issue when selecting an input(seems iphone specific as android is working as expected). keyboard is causing my top div to disappear to the top of the screen(while it should stay at the top of the screen) when i select my input(which is in the bottom div)
This is just a quick jsfiddle to see what my problem is(tried even using nav now still without luck -fixed-top and fixed-bottom), when using only the bottom or top it is working correct, but combined seems to be a problem. I've tried searching google without success:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-blend navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9">
             <span>Text top</span>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JPVeldtman/pju12ako/

Comment: Guess no answers, anybody else having this problem?